# Blazor DI – How to access a service in a class that is not a Blazor component?

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor

I have a background class that is not a Blazor component, and I want to use the built-in logger (ILogger) service.

I can’t use “[Inject]” on a property (because it’s not a component), and I can’t use the supported constructor injection because the constructor has other parameters (i.e. not just the single ILogger parameter). I have looked for something like “Application.GetService” (similar to what I've used other IOC implementations) that I could use in the constructor but can’t find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: `I can’t use the supported constructor injection because the constructor has other parameters` - that doesn't mean you can't add one more, if necessary.

Comment: @RogerWolf - Sorry, I wasn’t clear – my class implements a service that I am hoping to manage with AddSingleton in Startup. The docs on DI state the following: “One constructor must exist whose arguments can all be fulfilled by DI. Additional parameters not covered by DI are allowed if they specify default values.” I need to specify those additional parameters, I can’t rely on defaults.

Answer (score 1):

It *looks* like you need to register the default values for your service.
You can do it in `Startup.cs` and in `ConfigureServices` something like `services.AddTransient(<your service>)`.

If you want to be able to get a service at runtime, you can either inject an `IServiceProvider` with it's `.GetService<>()` method, or if you want to be able to call it without DI you can create a singleton that you register when your app starts up. The singleton will have a property for the service provider that you can then call from whatever service you would like (although I'd recommend against this - rather use DI)

It's also possible to combine the MS DI with other DI containers via an adapter. It seems that you already have a DI solution for your service, and this may be the best way forward if that's the case. In your `CreateHostBuilder()` setup method start with a `.UseServiceProviderFactory()` to use a different container. You'll need to find the correct adapter for your container though